# How to convert the co-efficients in these inequalities from float to int in Sympy?

Tags: python, math, sympy

I have the following expressions -

```
x > 4.5
2x + y == 4.5
```

I would like to get rid of the floating point numbers in the coefficients and convert them into integers. How can I do this using Sympy? (or any other python library for that matter). I have been racking my brains for hours now.

BTW, the expected output should be -

```
2x > 9
4x + 2y == 9
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Often, once they're in floating point they're ruined because floating point cannot represent very many fractions exactly. However, 4.5 can be represented exactly. I'm not familiar with everything that sympy can do, but if you want to fix it before sympy you can use the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module and construct the `Decimal` object using the string form. So don't do `x = decimal.Decimal(0.1)`, instead do `x = decimal.Decimal('0.1')`. Then you can use a method like `as_integer_ratio()` and multiply both side by the denominator.

Comment: You can convert the floats to exact rational numbers with `nsimplify`.

Comment: Yes, but I don’t want the fractions. nsimplify just converts the 0.5 to 1/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `nsimplify()` on the relation and multiply both sides by the denominator of the RHS, like the following.

```
from sympy import nsimplify, Rel
from sympy.abc import x

r0 = x > 4.5

r = nsimplify(r0)
q = r.rhs.q
r = Rel(r.lhs * q, r.rhs * q, r.rel_op)

print([r0, r])
```

This outputs

```
[x > 4.5, 2*x > 9]
```

If you want to handle coefficients in the LHS, you can use `primitive()` like the following.

```
from sympy import nsimplify, Rel, lcm
from sympy.abc import x, y

r0 = 2*x - 0.4*y <= 0.5

r = nsimplify(r0)
g, _ = r.lhs.primitive()
q = lcm(g.q, r.rhs.q)
r = Rel(r.lhs * q, r.rhs * q, r.rel_op)

print([r0, r])
```

This outputs

```
[2*x - 0.4*y <= 0.5, 20*x - 4*y <= 5]
```

Comment: This method doesn't work for 2*x - 0.4*y <= 0.5

Comment: Of cause it does not. I assumed handling a float only at the RHS. There is no generic method that covers all cases. Anyway, I will update the answer so it works at least for such cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear all denominators (even those that may be symbolic) then this might be a robust way to do so:

```py
def clear_relden(r):
    from sympy.core.relational import Relational
    from sympy import Piecewise
    assert isinstance(r, Relational)
    n, d = zip(*[i.as_numer_denom() for i in r.args])
    l = lcm(*d)
    args = [n[i]*l/d[i] for i in range(2)]
    return Piecewise(
        (r.func(*args), l>0),
        (r.reversed.func(*args), l<0))
```

For example,

[image]

If you have floats, then pass `nsimplify(r, rational=True)`.

Comment: This returns an assertion error whenever I use the '==' relationship operator. I try removing the assertion but then the lcm is always 1

Comment: If you use `==` it will give True or False; use `Eq(left, right)` instead of `left == right`.